# Dummy text inside the marginal note doesn't continue to next pages

Tags: geometry, marginpar, blindtext

This is my little MWE,

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{geometry}
    \geometry{
        includemp, % or include something else?
        paper=a4paper,
        marginparwidth=45mm
        }

\begin{document}
    Of course \marginpar{\blindtext[7]} \blindtext[7]
\end{document}
```

And the output is,

[image]

**Why dummy text in the marginal note doesn't continue to next pages?**

Comment: a marginpar is a parbox, and boxes never split across pages on their own.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle How can I make it possible to **split across pages**?

Comment: If you knew how much room you had left on the first page you could put the note into a \savebox, use \vsplit and output two margin notes.  If the second doesn't automatically float to the next page, you could use \afterpage.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use the paracol package and make the margin note area into a column.

Answer (score 3):

I'm entering this as a different answer since it is based on `\vsplit` and has none of the drawbacks of the `paracol` approach.  Note that it takes two runs to compute the distance to the bottom of the text area.

`\marginflow` is used instead of `\marginpar`.  `\marginrepeat` is only used in `\afterpage`.

Interestingly, without all the `\newpage`s this will only go for 3 pages.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
    \geometry{
        includemp, % or include something else?
        paper=a4paper,
        marginparwidth=45mm
        }

\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\newlength{\bottom}
\newsavebox{\marginparbox}

\newcommand{\marginflow}[1]% #1 = text
 {\strut\tikz[remember picture,overlay]% compute distance to bottom of text area
    {\pgfextracty{\bottom}{\pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{current page text area}{south}}{\pgfpointorigin}}%
    \global\bottom=\bottom}%
    \advance\bottom by 0.4\baselineskip
    \parbox{\marginparwidth}{\global\setbox\marginparbox=\vbox{#1}}%
    \ifdim\bottom>\dimexpr\ht\marginparbox+\dp\marginparbox\relax
      \marginpar{\raisebox{\dimexpr 0.6\baselineskip-\height}{\usebox{\marginparbox}}}%
    \else
      \setbox1=\vsplit\marginparbox to \bottom
      \marginpar{\raisebox{\dimexpr 0.6\baselineskip-\height}{\usebox1}}%
      \ifdim\ht\marginparbox>-\dp\marginparbox
        \afterpage{\marginrepeat}%
      \fi
    \fi\ignorespaces}

\newcommand{\marginrepeat}{\vspace*{-\baselineskip}%
  \ifdim\textheight>\dimexpr\ht\marginparbox+\dp\marginparbox\relax
  \marginpar{\raisebox{\dimexpr 0.6\baselineskip-\height}{\usebox{\marginparbox}}}%
\else
  \setbox1=\vsplit\marginparbox to \textheight
  \marginpar{\raisebox{\dimexpr 0.6\baselineskip-\height}{\usebox1}}%
  \ifdim\ht\marginparbox>-\dp\marginparbox
    \afterpage{\marginrepeat}%
  \fi
\fi}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
So here I am going on and on about absolutely nothing when I happen to mention something which I want to 
describe in the margins HERE  \marginflow{\blindtext[7]} then continue as if nothing had happened.
\null\newpage
\null\newpage
\null\newpage
\null\newpage
\null\newpage
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The drawback with this solution is that you can't just insert the "note" into the middle of a sentence or paragraph.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
    \geometry{
        includemp, % or include something else?
        paper=a4paper,
        textwidth=418.25368pt,% \the\dimexpr \textwidth+\marginparsep+\marginparwidth\relax
        marginparsep=0pt,
        marginparwidth=0pt
        }
\usepackage{paracol}
  \setcolumnwidth{\dimexpr \textwidth-45mm-\columnsep\relax,45mm}
  \twosided

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\begin{paracol}{2}
Of course 
\switchcolumn*\blindtext[7]\switchcolumn
as I was saying
\end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

---

This uses `\everypar` to perform the switch at the beginning of the paragraph (with a vertical offset).  It takes two runs, since the information from `\marginpar` is stored in the aux file.  The limit is only one `\marginpar` per paragraph.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
    \geometry{
        includemp, % or include something else?
        paper=a4paper,
        textwidth=418.25368pt,% \the\dimexpr \textwidth+\marginparsep+\marginparwidth\relax
        marginparsep=0pt,
        marginparwidth=0pt
        }
\usepackage{paracol}
  \setcolumnwidth{\dimexpr \textwidth-45mm-\columnsep\relax,45mm}
  \twosided

\makeatletter
\newcounter{absparagraph}
\newlength{\marginpar@offset}
\newif\ifmarginpar
\newif\ifrepeatpar

\newcommand{\newparagraph}[2]% #1 = pragraph, #2 = y location
{\expandafter\gdef\csname paragraph@#1\endcsname{#2}}

\newcommand{\newmarginpar}[3]% #1 = pragraph, #2 = y location, #3 = text
{\expandafter\gdef\csname marginpar@y@#1\endcsname{#2}%
 \expandafter\gdef\csname marginpar@text@#1\endcsname{#3}}

\renewcommand{\marginpar}[1]% #1=text
{\pdfsavepos
 \protected@write\@auxout{}{\string\newmarginpar{\theabs@paragraph}%
   {\noexpand\number\pdflastypos}{#1}}\ignorespaces}%

\newcommand{\AtBeginParagraph}{\ifmarginpar\else
  \ifrepeatpar\repeatparfalse
  \else
    \stepcounter{absparagraph}%
    \xdef\theabs@paragraph{\theabsparagraph}%
    \strut\pdfsavepos
    \protected@write\@auxout{}{\string\newparagraph{\theabs@paragraph}%
      {\noexpand\number\pdflastypos}}%
    \@ifundefined{paragraph@\theabs@paragraph}{}{%
      \@ifundefined{marginpar@text@\theabs@paragraph}{}{%
        \global\marginpar@offset=\csname paragraph@\theabs@paragraph\endcsname sp\relax
        \global\advance\marginpar@offset by -\csname marginpar@y@\theabs@paragraph\endcsname sp\relax
        \vspace{-\baselineskip}%
        \marginpartrue
        \switchcolumn*
        \vspace*{\marginpar@offset}\csname marginpar@text@\theabs@paragraph\endcsname
        \switchcolumn
        \marginparfalse\repeatpartrue}}%
  \fi
\fi}
\makeatother

\AtBeginDocument{\everypar{\AtBeginParagraph}}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\begin{paracol}{2}
So here I am going on and on about absolutely nothing when I happen do mention somtehing to which I want to 
describe in the margins HERE  \marginpar{\blindtext[7]} then continue as if nothing had happened.
\end{paracol}
\end{document}
```