# Margin floats running off the end of a page

Tags: floats, memoir, marginpar

I'm using the `memoir` class with the `\footnotesinmargin` option, and having an issue with the resulting sidenote float position. It seems like LaTeX is only concerned with the *top* of margin floats, and not at all with the float as a whole. Thus, if you put a float in the margin at a certain place in the main text, the float will always start there or below, even if that causes it to run past the end of the page - LaTeX won't push it up to compensate. If you have a series of margin floats, the whole block of starts right where the first one is triggered in the body text, even if it would be better to start higher.

This image is an example of how the margin notes run off past the bottom of the page, and they would run beyond the sheet edge if they were long enough. This is despite the fact that there is more than enough space above to simply displace them upwards and avoid the issue.

[image: Margin notes problem]

Is there any way to make a bottom limit on margin float positioning that overrides the top-based placement when necessary?

(It seems odd to me that this isn't part of LaTeX's native float positioning algorithm.)

Comment: LaTeX's native float positioning algorithm hasn't been designed to deal with margin notes, but for material floating around multiple pages (i.e. tables, figures and so on) and I do not even know whether memoir uses this mechanism for margin notes (it would seem odd). That said margin notes always have been a problem in LaTeX. Please provide a minimal compilable example (MWE) to help us help you.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/314125/dummy-text-inside-the-marginal-note-doesnt-continue-to-next-pages

Answer (score 2):

`memoir` does not have a `footnotesinmargin` option, although it does have a `\footnotesinmargin` switch paired with a `\footnotesatfoot` switch.

As you have not shown an MWE we have little idea of what you have, or have not, done.

My guess is that you should use `\sidefootnote` instead of `\footnote` and `\footnotesinmargin`.

I'm not prepared to spend time on creating an MWE just as you haven't. GOM