# Automatic positioning of marginpar (to avoid page overflow)

Tags: floats, marginpar

I am using marginpar to margin notes in a book. My problem is that if I add a `\marginpar` too close to the bottom of a page, the margin will overflow the bottom of the page.

For instance, using the following code, the margin not is not fully visible as it overflows (see below).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-5]
\marginpar{\tiny \lipsum[1-1]}
\end{document}
```

Of course, I could manually modify the place of margins like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\marginpar{\tiny \lipsum[1-1]}
\lipsum[3-5]
\end{document}
```

But this requires moving all `\marginpar` each time I change a paragraph in the document. Ideally, I would prefer if latex could automatically move my marginpar up to avoid overflowing the bottom of the page.

**Question**: Is there a way to ask latex to place marginpar automatically? (like the arguments [t] or [h] of `figure`). Or should I used another package? (marginnote?)

---

The result that I do not want: 
[image: not what I want]

What I would prefer: 
[image: what I want]

For my document, I am using the `scrbook` and `classicthesis` but the problem also occurs with the class `article`.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/320065/marginpar-start-at-top-of-page/320077?r=SearchResults&s=2|28.5825#320077, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/314125/dummy-text-inside-the-marginal-note-doesnt-continue-to-next-pages/314143?r=SearchResults&s=10|13.2899#314143, and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215322/multiple-marginnote-commands-on-the-same-line-in-math-environment/216037?r=SearchResults&s=20|7.6621#216037

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does this code solve your problem?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand{\bmarginpar}[1]{\marginpar{\parbox[b]{\marginparwidth}{\tiny#1}}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-5]
\bmarginpar{\lipsum[1]}

\lipsum[6-10]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this works.

Comment: I just modified your command to make it work with the style of classithesis, which ends up: \newcommand{\bmarginpar}[1]{\marginpar[%
  {\parbox[b]{\marginparwidth}{\flushright\footnotesize\textit{#1}}}]{%
    \parbox[b]{\marginparwidth}{\flushleft\footnotesize\textit{#1}}}}

Comment: That's fine! Of course, you must have not too many margin notes in a page – it is not as automatic as one  could hope.

Answer (score 1):

The `memoir` class (an extension to `book`, `report` and `article` classes) provides a `\sidebar{<text>}` macro whereby `<text>` is written in the margin starting near the top of the textblock. If `<text>` is long it may continue onto the next page(s). Several `\sidebar`s can be used on a page, printed in order and continuing on to further pages if necessary.
The manual (`> texdoc memoir`) has more details on how to control which margin, fonts, spacing, etc.